# Oracle XE 21c: cannot associate tablespace with user

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, tablespace, createuser

This is the first time that I am using Oracle.

I am using Oracle XE 21c, within a Docker container (`gvenzl/oracle-xe:latest`).

- I create a tablespace.
- I create a user, and I want to associate the previously create tablespace to the use (as default tablespable).

As `SYSTEM`, I create the tablespace `CONCERTO_DATA`. Everything is fine:

```
create TABLESPACE CONCERTO_DATA
    datafile 'concerto_data.dbf' size 10M
    autoextend on
    next 512K
    maxsize unlimited;
```

Then I create the user:

```
CREATE USER CONCERTO IDENTIFIED BY "password"
       TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;
GRANT DBA, CREATE ANY TYPE  TO CONCERTO;
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_AQADM TO CONCERTO;
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_AQ    TO CONCERTO;
GRANT AQ_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE TO CONCERTO;
GRANT CONNECT TO CONCERTO;
GRANT CREATE TYPE TO CONCERTO;
select username, default_tablespace from dba_users where username = 'CONCERTO';
```

Everything is fine. The default tablespace associated with the user `CONCERTO` is `USERS`.

I try to associate the previously created tablespace `CONCERTO_DATA`:

```
alter user CONCERTO default tablespace CONCERTO_DATA;
```

Then, a get a strange error:

```
[99999][65048] ORA-65048: erreur détectée lors du traitement de l'instruction DDL en cours dans la base de données pluggable XEPDB1
ORA-00959: le tablespace 'CONCERTO_DATA' n'existe pas
Position: 0
```

It says that the tablespace `CONCERTO_DATA` does not exist.

However, the table space exists:

```
select tablespace_name, con_id, STATUS from cdb_tablespaces WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME='CONCERTO_DATA';
```

Result is:

```
CONCERTO_DATA, 1, ONLINE
```

I have tried to associate the tablespace to the user during the user's creation:

```
CREATE USER CONCERTO IDENTIFIED BY "password"
       DEFAULT TABLESPACE CONCERTO_DATA
       TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;
```

But, I get the same error.

I have tried to create the tablespace using the user `CONCERTO` (instead of `SYSTEM`). But, I get the same error.

I think that the error is related to the container ID (`COND_ID=1`).

```
SELECT CON_ID, NAME FROM V$CONTAINERS;
```

Result:

```
1, CDB$ROOT
2, PDB$SEED
3, XEPDB1
```

I think that the container ID for the tablespace `CONCERTO_DATA` should be 3 (instead of 1). But I have no idea how to change it.

Answer (score 3):

You probably created the TABLESPACE in the CDB because you forgot to

```
alter session set container = XEPDB1 ;
```